# Change datatype of a sequence H2DB

Tags: java, oracle, h2

I need to change the returned value of a sequence stored into a H2DB, when i call nextVal through a direct SQL query H2 return a BigInt and i need a BigDecimal.

I can't cast or convert this value, I need H2 returning a BigDecimal.

How I can do that?

EDIT: I can't change the Java code beacuse I'm testing so cast or convert the request value from DB is not a option.

Comment: I'm interested in this question as well. I'll keep doing research on my own, but I hope this question gets more attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create you own patched version of H2, if you are allowed to replace the H2 jar file.

In `org.h2.expression.Function` change

```
    addFunctionNotDeterministic("NEXTVAL", NEXTVAL,
            VAR_ARGS, Value.LONG);
```

to

```
    addFunctionNotDeterministic("NEXTVAL", NEXTVAL,
            VAR_ARGS, Value.DECIMAL);
```

and in `org.h2.expression.SequenceValue` change

```
@Override
public Value getValue(Session session) {
    long value = sequence.getNext(session);
    session.setLastIdentity(ValueLong.get(value));
    return ValueLong.get(value);
}

@Override
public int getType() {
    return Value.LONG;
}
```

to

```
@Override
public Value getValue(Session session) {
    long lv = sequence.getNext(session);
    ValueDecimal value = ValueDecimal.get(BigDecimal.valueOf(lv)); 
    session.setLastIdentity(value);
    return value;
}

@Override
public int getType() {
    return Value.DECIMAL;
}
```

Comment: Didn't test this, but the code changes seem to be straight foward.

Comment: Interesting, I will have to test and get back to you. So far, this seems like the best approach I've seen.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to take the code from [wero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3215527/wero)'s answer and make this into a feature in H2 itself.

This GitHub fork: https://github.com/portofrotterdam/h2database returns BigDecimals instead of BigInteger/longs when using 'MODE=Oracle' in H2, making it more compatible with Oracle's database.

I've requested a pull to the master so perhaps this behaviour will be available in h2database.

Comment: Final update (didn't mention it here yet):

This has now been fixed and merged into H2, since 1.4.200.
(https://github.com/h2database/h2database/releases/tag/version-1.4.200)